# Finding domain of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Stumped at this question: Given that $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = \sqrt{1-x}$, find the domains of $f . g(x)$ and $g . f(x)$.

For the first one, I know that $f . g(x)$ is $(\sqrt{1-x})^2 = 1-x$, but from here how do I find the domain of the function? The answer is supposedly $x \le 1$.

Likewise for the second one, I get $g . f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and am not sure how to continue. The answer is apparently $-1 \le x \le 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square root of a negative is not real, so your domain is every real number that does not give you a negative square root.